# Find distance between two points inside a polygon without touching lines in R

Tags: r, spatial

I am measuring distance between points that are inside a polygon that is of irregular shape. Using the dist function, the distance is measured in a straight line, that sometimes crosses the lines (borders) of the polygon.

Is there a way to find the shortes "path" without touching the points using R?
I am adding an image as example, I am currently measuring distance between points (blue line) but it corsses the polygon. How to calculate the yellow lines?

THANKS!

[image]

EDIT:
Here is some code to create a polygon, and two points:

```
library(sf)  # 

mypolygon = data.frame(x = c(-5,-5, 5, 5,3,-3,4, -5),  
                       y = c(-5,5,5,-5,0,0,-4, -5))



p1 = st_as_sf(mypolygon, coords = c("x", "y"));  # create a polygon object
p3 = summarise(p1, do_union = FALSE);     # combines the points into one vector
p4 = st_cast(p3, "LINESTRING");           # makes a line of the points
plot(p4)
point<-data.frame(x = c(2,4.8),  ## added a return point
                   y = c(-4,-4))
points(point,pch=19,cex=2)
```

Which results in the following:
[image]

Comment: Interesting. So, `sf` creates your 'playing field'. I'm not very good swimming with sharks and sea crocodiles, so meeting up with my friend, p2, or if I invited him over (and he really doesn't like sharks...), we seek shortest path(s), which I believe is approached either via 'visibility graphs' , delauny triangulating, ray tracing and the google hunt in on in search of an r approach that respects 'don't swim zones', or write the logic for one, kiinda a game graphics problem that I'm sure has be resolved (somewhere).

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305070/finding-shortest-path-without-barriers-using-the-sf-package-in-r

Comment: and potentially: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leastcostpath/vignettes/leastcostpath-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Using your poly data, changing slightly by adding an 'ID' and using `library(sfheaders)` to simplify `sf` object creation from a data.frame.

```
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(spdep)
library(igraph)

mypolygon_df = data.frame(x = c(-5,-5, 5, 5,3,-3,4, -5),  
                       y = c(-5,5,5,-5,0,0,-4, -5), L1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
mypolygon_sf = sfheaders::sf_polygon(
obj = mypolygon_df, 
x = 'x',
y = 'y',
polygon_id = 'L1')

point<-data.frame(x = c(2,4.8),  ## added a return point
                   y = c(-4,-4))

fromto_pts = sfheaders::sf_point(
 obj = point,
 x = 'x',
 y = 'y'
 )
```

The trick is to get a grid within `mypolygon_sf` small enough that it is sufficiently space filling while excluding the 'not a path/don't swim here' zone.

```
n50 = c(50,50)
 mypoly_hex50 = st_make_grid(
 mypolygon_sf, 
 cellsize = c(diff(st_bbox(mypolygon_sf)[c(1,3)]), diff(st_bbox(mypolygon_sf)[c(2,4)]))/n50,
 offset = st_bbox(mypolygon_sf)[c('xmin', 'ymin')],
 n50,
 what = 'polygon',
 square = FALSE
 )
```

Next we, at minimum, show that we can exclude the 'don't swim' zone

```
contains_hex50 = st_contains_properly(mypolygon_sf, mypoly_hex50)
```

contains_hex50 is an index that reduces polys under consideration from
all mypoly_hex50 to those within mypolygon_sf. It currently uses mypoly_hex50 numbering so we want to create another object that is just the properly contained polys in the hex to get desired index.

```
contained_hex50 <- mypoly_hex50[unlist(contains_hex50)]
centroid_contained_hex50 = st_centroid(contained_hex50)
```

find which polys intersect with our from/to points

```
from = st_intersects(fromto_pts[1, ], contained_hex50)
 to = st_intersects(fromto_pts[2, ], contained_hex50)
 from
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
was `intersects'
 1: 1622
 to
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
was `intersects'
 1: 2144
#png(filename = 'dists_within_poly_points_sof_76000050.png')
# plot(contained_hex50)
# plot(st_geometry(mypolygon_sf), add = TRUE, col = NA)
# points(point, pch = 19, cex = 1, col = c('blue', 'red'))
# dev.off()
```

Next is to take all our polygons to neighbors using `spdep::poly2nb` or that gets us to an object usable by `igraph`...

[image]

Check again on our from/to polygon indices

```
unlist(st_intersects(fromto_pts[c(1,2), ], contained_hex50))
[1] 1622 2144
```

And then

```
nb_hex50 = spdep::poly2nb(contained_hex50)
graph_nb_hex50 = igraph::graph_from_adj_list(nb_hex50)
this_short_path = igraph::shortest_paths(graph_nb_hex50, from = 1622, to = 2144)
shortest_path = as.integer(this_short_path$vpath[[1]])
```

Keeping in mind that this is adjacency between hexagons, this is likely the shortest, by adjacent hexagon route. One could decompose the hexagons to linestrings and perhaps find a shorter 'shortest route', but I took the challenge to be to establish the (1D) obstacle and go around that.

Given the prior constraints, the polygon, hexagons, the placement of the origin/destination points, the shortest route via hexagon will remain the same, irrespective of size of hexagon (check n(150,150) for hex grid).

[image]

Changing the basis to linestring, the following gives insight into sequences useful to constructing horizontal and diagonal linestrings.

```
plot.new()
png(filename = 'sequence_to_lines_among_centroids2.png')
plot(cent_hex50, cex = 0.5)
plot(cent_hex50[seq(12, 3038, 59)], col = 'red', add = TRUE)
plot(cent_hex50[seq(12, 3038, 29)], col = 'blue', add = TRUE)
plot(cent_hex50[seq(12, 3038, 30)], col = 'green', add = TRUE)
plot(cent_hex50[seq(42, 3038, 59)], col = 'orange', add = TRUE)
plot(cent_hex50[seq(42, 3038, 29)], col = 'orange', add = TRUE)
plot(cent_hex50[seq(42, 3038, 30)], col = 'orange', add = TRUE)
dev.off()
png 
  3
```

[image]

`sort(rep(seq[12,3038, 59], times = 2))` will be useful here in constructing line segments,

```
length(sort(rep(seq(12, 3038, 59), times = 2)))
[1] 104
sort(rep(seq(12, 3038, 59), times = 2))[2:103]
  [1]   12   71   71  130  130  189  189  248  248  307  307  366  366  425  425
 [16]  484  484  543  543  602  602  661  661  720  720  779  779  838  838  897
 [31]  897  956  956 1015 1015 1074 1074 1133 1133 1192 1192 1251 1251 1310 1310
 [46] 1369 1369 1428 1428 1487 1487 1546 1546 1605 1605 1664 1664 1723 1723 1782
 [61] 1782 1841 1841 1900 1900 1959 1959 2018 2018 2077 2077 2136 2136 2195 2195
 [76] 2254 2254 2313 2313 2372 2372 2431 2431 2490 2490 2549 2549 2608 2608 2667
 [91] 2667 2726 2726 2785 2785 2844 2844 2903 2903 2962 2962 3021
#
```

**Hex centroids to linestring**

Here `mypoly_hex50` is called `hex50_centroids`. Starting with vertical lines between centroids, we want to make an index of our centroid points as a matrix

```
length(hex50_centroid)
[1] 3038
hex50_vert_mtx = matrix(sort(rep(seq(1, 3038, 1), times = 2))[2:(2*length(hex50_centroid)-1)], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
head(hex50_vert_mtx, n = 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
tail(hex50_vert_mtx, n = 2)
        [,1] [,2]
[3036,] 3036 3037
[3037,] 3037 3038
```

Vertical lines are the most straight forward, but to make linestrings for our horizontal(s) and diagonals(s), we need to check our indices such that our `tail(` case doesn't result in `NA`(s).

```
vert_lines_lst = list()

for (i in 1:dim(hex50_vert_mtx)[1]) {
vert_lines_lst[[i]] = st_cast(st_union(hex50_centroid[hex50_vert_mtx[i, 1]], hex50_centroid[hex50_vert_mtx[i, 2]]), 'LINESTRING')
}
vert_lines_pre_collect = do.call(rbind, vert_lines_lst)
vert_lines_collect = st_geometrycollection(x=vert_lines_pre_collect)
# extract
vert_lines_sf = st_collection_extract(vert_lines_collect, 'LINESTRING')
vert_lines_sf
Geometry set for 3037 features 
Geometry type: LINESTRING
```

returning to `st_contains_properly`

```
# st_contains_properly returns an index
vert_lines_contains_idx = st_contains_properly(mypolygon_sf, vert_lines_sf)
vert_lines_contained_sf = vert_lines_sf[unlist(vert_lines_contains_idx)]
# plot(vert_lines_contained_sf)
```

There are two different indices for horizontal and diagonal lines. We follow the steps just used, but adjust our indices as indicated.